# How to get Model value in javascript function and pass it to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model on my CSHTML page that which I use this way:

```
@model Web.Models.Element

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Company"))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Person)

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"> Company Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body collapse" id="screenCompanySearch">
        <form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="post">
            <fieldset style="margin: 20px;">
                <legend>Search</legend>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
                        @Html.Label("Company Name")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Company.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript function is called by a button click this way:

```
$("#btnSearch").on("click", function() { searchCompany(); })'
```

In my JavaScript function I need to get this Model entirely loaded with the TextBoxFor values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchCompany() {
   var data = $("#formSearch").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("SearchCompany", "Company"))",
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: alert("sucesso!")
    });
}
</script>
```

My Controller method is being loaded correctly, but the model passed in the Ajax "data" parameter is not filled with the TextBoxFor values.

This is my Controller ActionResult for the View:

```
public ActionResult Consulta()
    {
        Element model = new Element();
        model.Person = new Person();

        return View(model);
    }
```

What is happening is that my Model is being instantiated on my Controller but the values from the TextBoxFor is not recorded on the properties of the Model.

How can I solve this? Thanks for now.

UPDATED

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
     @Html.Label("Person Name")
     @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Person.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

So, 'c' equals my Element object. When I reach the Controller Method "Search", the parameter Element passed via ajax call does not instantiate the Element.Person which gives me Person = null.

In my ActionResult I have:

```
Element model = new Element();
model.Person = new Person();
```

Element class:

```
public Element()
{
    this.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
    this.DataType = new DataType();

}

public int ID_Element { get; set; }
public int ID_ElementType { get; set; }

public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
public virtual DataType DataType { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person {get; set; }
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SearchCompany(Element model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling the `searchCompany` js method ?  and what are you passing to it ?

Comment: Like this on my script section: $("#btnSearch").on("click", function() { searchCompany(model) }); @Shyju

Comment: what is `model` there ? Is that your js object ?. Add the relevant code to your original question.

Comment: Are you trying to send the same model (`Element` object) back to the server via your ajax call, but with the `Company.Name` property value filled with the text box value ? Why do you want to do that ? If you are doing a search. All you need is the search key. rite ? why you need the entire model there ?

Comment: Actually it is "Model" on the parameter. By doing this @model Web.Models.Element my object Model it's ready to use on my page, right? Once I instantiate it on my ActionResult method on Controller.

Comment: You can pass the `Model` you passed to your js method if you need. But why you want to pass the entire model ? All you need is the search key (the text user entered in the search textbox) .rite ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to pass the text box values to my model object Element and send it to the controller method via ajax call.

Comment: I have to pass my entire model because I have some more 10 field inputs on my html, all properties that I'll need to use on my controller.

Comment: Are those all inside the form ? Then you should simply serialize your form and send it `$("#YourFormId").serialize()` as the data property of your ajax call.

Comment: Yes, all of them inside my form. But when I do var data = $("formSearch").serialize(); the data property returns "".

Comment: your jquery selector is wrong. If you are using id selector. you should have a `#` prefix. The code you shared has a form tag but it does not have any id.

Comment: Yes, it has an ID like this: id="formSearch". Then in my code I have var data = $("#formSearch").serialize(); (on the comment I forgot to put the # prefix, but in my code it is right.

Comment: You should update your question with the **relevant part of the actual code** you are trying.

Comment: Done! There is my actual code after your tips. My data parameter on the ajax call after include the serialize its still == ""

Comment: your form do not have the id "formSearch". Check the view source of your page.

Comment: But this is not right? <form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="post">

Comment: Oh I see. You have nested forms. nested forms are invalid. Remove the nested forms.

Comment: Ok. But where do I pass the ID property of the form instead? On the BeginForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialize method is not giving your the serialized version of the form because you have nested form tags.

The `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Company"))` will create an outer form tag and you have your other form inside that, hence creating a nested form structure. Nested forms are invalid. You can have 2 forms in the same page, parallel to each other, not nested.

If you fix the nested form issue, the serialize method will give you valid string for you form inputs.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Company"))
{
   <!-- Your other form -->
}

<form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="post">
    <fieldset style="margin: 20px;">
        <legend>Search</legend>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
            @Html.Label("Company Name")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Company.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Keep in mind that, the serialize method will give you the input element values of items inside this specific form. If you want to send some other data (ex : Id), you need to keep that in an input field inside this form.

Comment: Nice! Now I have my data object filled with the values from the input fields! But in my Controller method now which object I should receive as a parameter? I mean, what I'll have to do to transform this serialized object from the form into my desired model on the controller?

Comment: If you use `Element` as the parameter of your action method, model binder will be able to map the posted data to it.

Comment: Wonderful! In my Element object I have an object Person that is coming null, even doing this on the controller action method: Element model = new Element(); and model.Person = new Person(); Why this is happening?

Comment: You have to have input elements for Person object properties in your form so that model binder will initialize that property as well.

Comment: In my serialized object I have the Element.Person.Name filled with the input values, but when I reach the Controller Action Method the object passed on the parameter contains Element.Person = null. I'll update the question with extra code.

Comment: Is your input like `<input type="text" name='Person.Name' value="a" />` Then it should work as long as it is in the same form.

Comment: I have TextBoxFor the same way. See my UPDATED code.

Comment: Is it inside the same form (`formSearch`) ? Then model binder will be able to map it when the serialized data is posted.

Comment: Yeah, inside the same form used before. Strange! I have other elements properties inside Element and all of them have bem instantiated, only Person is not.

Comment: is the Person property and name property settable ? Can you add the definition of your class and your `SearchCompany` action method ?

Comment: It should work fine then. Are you seeing `Person.Name` in the serialized string which you are sending to the server via ajax ?

Comment: Yes, like this: "Person=Web.Models.Person&Contact=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BWeb.Models.Contact%5D&DataType=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BWeb.Models.DataType%5D&Person.Name=rodrigo". But the "model" parameter has the Person = null.

Comment: As per the code you shared in the question, you will have one for `Company.Name` and  one for `PersonName`. Your serialized data looks totally different. Make sure you are serializing the correct form.

Comment: "Person=Web.Models.Person&Company=Web.Models.Company&Person.Name=rodr‌​igo&Company.Name=company". That's the correct form now, my mistake. That's my two classes and input fields on the form.

Comment: This is the problem `Person=Web.Models.Person`. How did you get that  ? Remove the code in your form which is doing that . Probably this part `@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Person)`

Comment: Wonderful! That's the problem! It works fine now! Thank you so much for your patience and help, man!